# How abstraction hide the main functionality in OOP

Tags: java, android, abstraction

Abstract method are not defined in abstract classes. it is compulsory to define their bodies in the subclass.

Now Suppose we are working on Asynctask and we have an abstract method in this class
 **doInBackground(Params... params)**

```
public class InsertAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Note, Void, Void> {

private NoteDao mNoteDao;

public InsertAsyncTask(NoteDao dao) {
    mNoteDao = dao;
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Note... notes) { 
    mNoteDao.insertNotes(notes); // How this function becomes thread save( goes in background) ?
    return null;
}
```

Here is AsyncTask class's Abstract method and one concrete method onPreExcute().

> ```
> /**
>  * Override this method to perform a computation on a background thread. The
>  * specified parameters are the parameters passed to {@link #execute}
>  * by the caller of this task.
>  *
>  * This method can call {@link #publishProgress} to publish updates
>  * on the UI thread.
>  *
>  * @param params The parameters of the task.
>  *
>  * @return A result, defined by the subclass of this task.
>  *
>  * @see #onPreExecute()
>  * @see #onPostExecute
>  * @see #publishProgress
>  */
> @WorkerThread
> protected abstract Result doInBackground(Params... params);
> ```

```
/**
 * Runs on the UI thread before {@link #doInBackground}.
 *
 * @see #onPostExecute
 * @see #doInBackground
 */
@MainThread
protected void onPreExecute() {
}

/**
 * <p>Runs on the UI thread after {@link #doInBackground}. The
 * specified result is the value returned by {@link #doInBackground}.</p>
 * 
 * <p>This method won't be invoked if the task was cancelled.</p>
 *
 * @param result The result of the operation computed by {@link #doInBackground}.
 *
 * @see #onPreExecute
 * @see #doInBackground
 * @see #onCancelled(Object) 
 */
```

Now Question is, where is the hidden implementation of making them asynchronous(I mean how abstract method doinbackground actually making things to work in background? as its abstract method which is nothing till their implementation in a subclass. Am I right?). As abstract methods are only defined in the subclasses and we didn't write any logic related to the thread in override method.

Comment: You are asking two questions here: 1. how does whatever you put in `doInBackground` get executed in the background 2. how does an abstract method hide the real implementation

Comment: actually, one question which is finding the hidden implementation of abstraction.

Comment: @Sweeper kindly help me out if you can and kindly tell me if my question is not clear. I have not got any proper answer.

Comment: What I mean is you should only ask one question per post. Please [edit] it so that it only has one question.

Answer (score 0):

How doInBackGround run on the background thread (see @WorkerThread):

```
    /**
 * Override this method to perform a computation on a background thread. The
 * specified parameters are the parameters passed to {@link #execute}
 * by the caller of this task.
 *
 * This method can call {@link #publishProgress} to publish updates
 * on the UI thread.
 *
 * @param params The parameters of the task.
 *
 * @return A result, defined by the subclass of this task.
 *
 * @see #onPreExecute()
 * @see #onPostExecute
 * @see #publishProgress
 */
@WorkerThread
protected abstract Result doInBackground(Params... params);
```

and now run it by WorkerRunnable

```
        mWorker = new WorkerRunnable<Params, Result>() {
        public Result call() throws Exception {
            mTaskInvoked.set(true);
            Result result = null;
            try {
                Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
                //noinspection unchecked
                result = doInBackground(mParams);
                Binder.flushPendingCommands();
            } catch (Throwable tr) {
                mCancelled.set(true);
                throw tr;
            } finally {
                postResult(result);
            }
            return result;
        }
    };
```

You can see the source code of AsyncTask by hold control + click on AsynkTask keyword for more information.

Comment: WorkerThread annotation is only to add a requirement of calling thread not for automatically using a specific thread. How you run it by workerRunnable? unclear answer.